# Type conversion `operator` function returning pointer to function

Tags: c++, ncurses, terminfo

I wanted a means of allowing `terminfo` escape sequences (esp. resulting from calls to `tparm()`) to be stored in strings, so I wrote this wrapper class.

```
class tputs_wrapper {
    private:
        static string *current;

    public:
        using putchar_like=int (*)(int);

        tputs_wrapper(string &s){
            s.clear();
            current=&s;
        }

        static int putchar(int ch){
            *current+=static_cast<unsigned char>(ch);
            return ch;
        }

        operator putchar_like(){ return putchar; }
};
string *tputs_wrapper::current=nullptr;
```

Which can be used as follows (crude example).

```
tputs(tparm(set_a_foreground, 196), 1, tputs_wrapper(sp));  // Invokes the type conversion operator for tupts' thrid arg.
tputs(tparm(exit_attribute_mode), 1, tputs_wrapper(ep));    // Ditto.
cout << sp << "Pink." << ep << "\nNormal\n";
```

**Question:** Is there a way of declaring the operator that allows the object of that class to be interpreted as a pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning `int` without resorting to the type alias `putchar_like`?

Comment: Would auto work there? ( Just curious, don't know)

Comment: Seems like it does, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/za5gQ0scibJJAqIy